# How to remove a file from git commit that is in multiple commits?

Tags: git

I have a couple of files that were added to various commits since I last pushed.  They are too large and cannot be pushed.  I used

```
git rm --cached <path to file>
```

and they don't show up when I check to see which files are being committed.  When I attempt to push, however, I still get an error saying that these two files are too large and cannot be pushed.

How do I completely remove these files from all of my commits so that I can push the rest of my changes?

Comment: This [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2100907) has several good replies.  But this [reply](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2158271/421195) is "better"(arguably "more instructive") than the accepted reply.  Please review all the replies before doing anything.

Comment: @paulsm4 I'd probably go with [filter-repo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61602985/184546) over filter-branch.

Comment: Good call :)  filter-repo is also one of the responses in the thread I cited: [100 times faster than git filter-branch and simpler](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61602985/421195).  Note the warning: `Do this on a copy of your repository. Many actions of filter-repo cannot be undone`

Comment: @paulsm4 Agreed. That warning is great advice. Fortunately, if you attempt to use `filter-repo` on anything other than a fresh clone, it won't work unless you provide the `-f` (force) option.

Comment: Thank you for the replies.  I am currently attempting to use BFG to remove these files and will confirm a solution once I have seen that it works.